# Why are data type sizes in Java and C++ different?

Tags: java, c++, types, primitive-types

For instance, real number in Java takes 8 byte while it only takes 4 byte in C++. Similarly, for character, Java takes 2 bytes, but C++ takes only 1 byte. Why are they of different size?

Comment: I didn't realize that C++ can handle "real numbers".

Comment: I think he means `real` as `floating-point`.

Comment: @chris Since he is talking about bytes, I would quote this, because `sizeof` doesn't return size in 8bit Bytes.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be, Good point. It really does get down in there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are stating isn't true. C and C++ don't have any fixed sized types (apart from those specified in `stdint.h`).

And if you didn't get you answer from that statement, here is an explicit one:

"There is a difference, because Java contains fixed sized data types, while all basic data types in C and C++ depend on the actual platform (machine architecture + operating system) the program is compiled for."

Comment: and the standard
http://www.kuzbass.ru:8086/docs/isocpp/expr.html#expr.sizeof

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I appreciate that. So, for two same programs developed in Java and C/C++, if the data type sizes are fixed in Java, does it mean Java requires more memory than C/C++ program during execution of program?

Comment: @ParanoidAndroid In general yes, but not because of this.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be Thanks for your response. So, is it because of architecture  and platform? If that is the reason, can I say data types on Java are fixed no matter the platform and architecture while C/C++ depends upon the architecture and platform in which the programs are being compiled and run?

Answer (score 2):

First, while the actual sizes of types in C++ is implemenation dependent
(and there are implementations where `char` has 9 bits), on most
platforms which support both languages, `float` and `double` have
exactly the same size in both C++ and Java.

As for `char`, the Java type `char` corresponds more or less to
`wchar_t` in C++; logically, it should be 4 bytes on most platforms, but
for various historical reasons, it is only 2 bytes on Windows, AIX and
in the Java runtime environment.

Java has no real equivalent to the C++ `char` type.

Answer (score 1):

c++ is depended on the platform. for example - int will be in the size of the word - 32 bit or 64 bit, depends on how new your computer is.

java is much more generic - it runs on a JVM that dfines the sizes. same case with C#. both are not depended on what OS and CPU you have.

Comment: Java isn't *more* generic, but less. It only runs on one platform, the JVM. So Java program always have the properties of this single platform.

Comment: but the JVM runs on basically every thing, and you don't need to recompile your code - one compilation and the code could run on linux,windows,IOS and more.

Comment: So do different JVM's do these sizes differently? Like hotspot and JRockit and IBM's JVM?

Answer (score 1):

The size of C++ types are *not* set in stone. The standard says (3.9.1
Fundamental types):

> Objects declared as characters (char) shall be large enough to store
>   any member of the implementation’s ba-  sic character set.

And after that:

> There are five standard signed integer types : “signed char”, “short
>   int”, “int”, “long int”, and “long
>                      long int”. In this list, each type provides at least as much storage as those preceding it in the list.
>
> <...>
>
> There are three floating point types: float, double, and long double.
>   The type double provides at least  as much precision as float, and the
>   type long double provides at least as much precision as double.

As you can see, no exact values are mentioned.

Comment: But minimums are imposed.  (Very indirectly, by the specified limit values of the constants in `<limits.h>`.)  `char` et al. must be at least 8 bits, `short` and `int` 16, `long` 32 and `long long` 64.  (And the unsigned types must have the same size as the corresponding signed type.)

Comment: @JamesKanze, true. My main point was that their size is mostly described as `at least <something>`.

Answer (score 1):

C and C++ don't have defined sizes for many types, but typically `float` is 4-bytes, just like in Java and `double` is 8-bytes just like in Java.  C doesn't have a standard byte type.

`char` in C is one byte but not guaranteed to be signed or unsigned.  In Java it is 2 bytes and guaranteed to be signed to support characters from 0 to 65535.

The difference here is that C was designed which 7 bit ASCII was all you need to support.  Java was designed when 16-bit characters seemed to be enough.  Ironically, Unicode not goes beyond 65535 so Java now supports code points as well using multiple `char`s

Comment: Actually, in C there is a standard byte type, `char`. It's the only type whose `sizeof` is guaranteed. `sizeof(char)==1`, everywhere. `C` doesn't have a standard octet type, though. `CHAR_BIT` can be >8.

Answer (score 0):

It's just that the language designed chose to use different default representations. Nothing more complex than that.

The size of `char` in Java for example was motivated by the desire to use 16-bit unicode characters (which require 2 bytes). This is a design decision that balanced a number of tradeoffs:

- They could have used 8-bit chars (as in C/C++) but then a significant number of useful unicode characters wouldn't fit in a single char.
- They could have used 32-bit characters to allow many more characters in the future (anticipating [UTF32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32)). But then a lot of those bits would be wasted most of the time

Note that you can have a 4-byte floating point number in Java - it's called `float` instead of `double` (which is 8 bytes)

Comment: I suspect that Java's choice of 16 bits for Unicode was not based on possible wasted memory, but on the fact that Unicode was only 16 bits when Java was standardized.

Comment: This answer is misguiding. Plus it doesn't really answer the question (as it only explains the Java side).

Comment: Thanks all for the valuable answers. I really appreciate that. So, for two same programs developed in Java and C++, does it mean Java requires more memory than C++ program during execution of program? While checking the data type sizes of Java in compared to C++, Java requires more bytes for string data type too (Number of letters + 2 bytes) while C++ requires Number of letters + 1 byte.

Answer (score 0):

> for character, Java takes 2 bytes, but C++ takes only 1 byte.

Because the standards say so.

For [java:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html)

> The Java 2 platform uses the UTF-16 representation in char arrays and in the String and 
>   StringBuffer classes.

For [C++:](http://www.kuzbass.ru:8086/docs/isocpp/expr.html#expr.sizeof)

> sizeof(char), sizeof(signed char) and sizeof(unsigned char) are 1;

Comment: But `sizeof(1)` still doesn't say how many bits.  I'm aware of implementations where `char` is 9 bits, and I've heard of some where it is 32 bits (and all integral types except `long long` have a size of 1).

Comment: @JamesKanze yes, but the OP didn't mention number of bits, so I didn't bother.

Comment: @pwned Yes, but one generally assumes that when someone mentions size in bytes, he means 8bit bytes.

Comment: Actually, number of bits is irrelevant and won't change my answer or his question.

Comment: @pwned Well, that would depend on what you call a byte. The C and C++ standards call a byte whatever size of char is, even if it is 32 bits. So if you are using the C and C++ standards notification, you are right, the number of bits doesn't matter.